# Stored procedure: "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I can't find what's wrong with the SELECT statement I'm trying to use on a stored procedure:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @TARIF = t.rea_est_tax_cla_ali_area, 
             @CHARACTERISTIC = t.rea_est_cha_id, 
             @USE = t.rea_est_use_id, 
             @TYPE = t.typ_rea_est_id, 
             ( ( CASE 
                   WHEN t.rea_est_tax_cla_ali_area IS NULL THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END ) + ( CASE 
                             WHEN t.rea_est_cha_id IS NULL THEN 1 
                             ELSE 0 
                           END ) + ( CASE 
                                       WHEN t.rea_est_use_id IS NULL THEN 1 
                                       ELSE 0 
                                     END ) + ( CASE 
                                                 WHEN t.typ_rea_est_id IS NULL 
                                               THEN 1 
                                                 ELSE 0 
                                               END ) ) AS NULLCOLUMNCOUNT 
FROM   dbo.tbl_real_estate_tax_classifier
```

Any help appreciated, I can't submit the entire procedure because of work regulations but the problem appears to be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reformatted your code with line breaks for readability.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    @TARIF = T.REA_EST_TAX_CLA_ALI_AREA, 
    @CHARACTERISTIC = T.REA_EST_CHA_ID, 
    @USE     = T.REA_EST_USE_ID, 
    @TYPE = T.TYP_REA_EST_ID,
    ((CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_TAX_CLA_ALI_AREA IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_CHA_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    +(CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_USE_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN T.TYP_REA_EST_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS NULLCOLUMNCOUNT 
FROM dbo.TBL_REAL_ESTATE_TAX_CLASSIFIER
```

Hopefully you see the problem now.  NULLCOLUMNCOUNT is your culprit.

Did you mean to write this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    @TARIF = T.REA_EST_TAX_CLA_ALI_AREA, 
    @CHARACTERISTIC = T.REA_EST_CHA_ID, 
    @USE     = T.REA_EST_USE_ID, 
    @TYPE = T.TYP_REA_EST_ID,
    @NULLCOLUMNCOUNT =    ((CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_TAX_CLA_ALI_AREA IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_CHA_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    +(CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_USE_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN T.TYP_REA_EST_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
FROM dbo.TBL_REAL_ESTATE_TAX_CLASSIFIER
```

Answer (score 3):

The error seems pretty clear - you are using part of the select to assign values to variables and part to return as a column.

Maybe you want something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    @TARIF = T.REA_EST_TAX_CLA_ALI_AREA, 
    @CHARACTERISTIC = T.REA_EST_CHA_ID, 
    @USE     = T.REA_EST_USE_ID, 
    @TYPE = T.TYP_REA_EST_ID,
    @NULLCOLUMNCOUNT = ((CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_TAX_CLA_ALI_AREA IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                       +(CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_CHA_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                       +(CASE WHEN T.REA_EST_USE_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                       +(CASE WHEN T.TYP_REA_EST_ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    FROM dbo.TBL_REAL_ESTATE_TAX_CLASSIFIER
```